# Reactive (Rx) build issue with .Net 4.5 and NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, .net-4.5, system.reactive, reactive-programming

This has caused me quite the embaressment today. While I was demoing Rx 2.x features and capabilities, I tried to build a NuGet enabled project which I copied from another computer.

Everything was downloaded correctly, the references are there! but I can't compile.

These two below assemblies are causing the issue. I am wondering if anyone has faced this issue with restroing Rx assemblies into a .Net 4.5 project.

**System.Reactive.Windows.Threading**

> Warning   11  The primary reference "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading,
>   Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading, Version=2.1.30214.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a
>   framework version which contains "System.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

And **System.Reactive.PlatformServices**

> Warning   26  The primary reference "System.Reactive.PlatformServices"
>   could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the
>   framework assembly "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be
>   resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "System.Reactive.PlatformServices" or retarget your
>   application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Couldn't compile:

> Error 73  The type or namespace name 'IScheduler' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   Error 74  The type or namespace name 'CompositeDisposable' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugger says this has something to do with either mixing references to .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 Rx DLLs in a project, or Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Comment: I think your physic mojo is on target! Fastest way to resolve is probably to uninstall/reinstall the nuget package Rx-Main - this will respect whatever .NET FX version you are using on that machine, but will leave it not matching the original.

Comment: After looking into the references, I found that the Rx Dlls pulled by NuGet in lib\net45 were .Net v4.0 dlls. So the issue was in the NuGet package itself.